# Why does function takes zero seconds to execute

Tags: python, numba

I have written the following code where I average the rows of a frame. I wanted to test the speed and compare it with using `np.mean`.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def test(frame):
    #np.mean(frame, axis=1)
    
    averages = []
    for i in range(480):
        summation = 0
        for j in range(640):
            summation += frame[i, j, 1]

        averages.append(summation/640)
    return averages

while True:
     a = time.time()
     test(frame)
     print("My program took {:.15f} seconds to run".format(time.time() - a))
```

When using `np.mean()`, I get average time around 6ms. When I remove it and use numba, the first iteration takes 100ms, but the subsequent take 0.000000000s. I want to know the exact speed of the code when using numba, because I am certain it doesn't take 0s to execute the code.

Comment: The function probably optimized to nothing, since it has no return value and no side-effects.  Do a `return averages` at the end, and it would be forced to actually do something when you call it.

Comment: adding the ```return``` statement still gives me 0s for execution. When I add a ```print(averages[0])``` I see it outputting between 10 - 1 ms. I assume this is because the ```print``` statement is costly. But without the print statement, would this mean that the function is just running too fast that my computer can't time it properly?

Comment: Also, for a true timing and to eliminate outliers, use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module instead of manually calculating time

Comment: The first call is compilation and runtime the second call is in the range of a few µs (the actual runtime). This timing method can be imprecise a such short runtime. Use timeit in Jupyter Notebooks, or just call it a few 100 times and than take the time.

Comment: I tried timing `print("My program took {:.15f} seconds to run".format(time.time() - a))`. Takes about 54µs, your function takes about 100µs. Don't expect any useful information from your timing method. The function you benchmark is just too simple (too short runtime)

Answer (score 0):

`time.time() - a` is 0ms in your case maybe because there is no return value at the end of your function.

Try adding `return averages` at the end of the function in order to return a calculated value.

Comment: It still takes 0ms with the return statement. When I add a ```print(averages[0])``` I see it outputting between 10 - 1 ms.